# What's the diffrence between snapshot-create and snapshot-create-as in virsh kvm?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, linux-kvm, snapshot

On my virtualization system there are some VMs. One of them was aimed for testing some services on it. So in this case I need to have the first state of that VM.

I searched for a solution found the `snapshot` as a good approach for it. Then searched further and found out that virsh can do it form by `snapshot-create`. But besides that, there is another command, `snapshot-create-as`. I read both of them, and both of them act the same.

Now my question is, what is the difference between `snapshot-create` and `snapshot-create-as`?

Please describe in detail!!

Answer (score 4):

```
# virsh help snapshot-create-as
Create a snapshot (disk and RAM) from arguments
```

vs.

```
# virsh help snapshot-create
Create a snapshot (disk and RAM) from XML
```

Apparently one can create an xml file using snapshot-create-as, then use that with snapshot-create.